# I am getting this error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Core.dll"

Tags: c#, linq, class, properties

I need to pass values into zeiresponse.TEnrlbp , which is a type  "ZetEnrlbp".Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

```
       ZEIsuCirroCreateBpCaResponse zeiresponse = new ZEIsuCirroCreateBpCaResponse();

       ZetEnrlbp brp = new ZetEnrlbp();


       brp.BuLangu = "English";
       brp.NameOrg1 = "Random";
       brp.NameOrg2 = "Random2";

      //Throws an exception here.
       zeiresponse.TEnrlbp.Select(c => c.NameOrg2 = "Name");

       zeiresponse.TEnrlbp.Select(s => s.NameOrg2 = "");
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you sure it's not supposed to be `==` in your `select`?

Comment: I suspect the problem is simply that `zeiresponse.TEnrlbp` is null... (and it's entirely unclear what you expect your `Select` calls to actually do...)

Comment: I think you should use Where to instead of Select: 
 zeiresponse.TEnrlbp.Where(c => c.NameOrg2 == "Name");

Comment: zeiresponse object has to be passed into another function, but before passing it, one of its property TEnrlbp which is a type "ZetEnrlp" has to be populated with some values. I am unable to do so because of this error.

Comment: I am trying to assign a value not filter it .So I think I can achive that via Select right?

Comment: What Skeet was trying to tell you is that you have to call new ZetEnrlp() inside ZEIsuCirroCreateBpCaResponse class to instantiate the TEnrlbp object to make it valid and accessible...or just reference it.

Comment: @WiiMaxx
I tried :

   zeiresponse.TEnrlbp =brp;  It gave me an error "Cannot Implicitly convert type "ZetEnrlbp" to "ZetEnrlbp[]"

Comment: If TEnrlb is an array of type ZetEnrlbp then brp has to be of the same type or: initialize the array (TEnrlbp) and go like TEnrlb[0] = brp.

Answer (score 0):

It's because "c" is null, that is why "c.NameOrg2" throws exception. Modify it like this:

```
zeiresponse.TEnrlbp.Where(c => с != null).Select(c => c.NameOrg2 = "Name");
```

or event like this:

```
zeiresponse.TEnrlbp.Select((c) => 
   {
        if (c == null) с = new ....; //typeof "с" constructor
        c.NameOrg2 = "Name";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception that is thrown when a null reference  is passed to a method / object that does not accept it as a valid argument.

By the way your question is not clear. please check your code again.